# Adding more than two Bar Button Items to a Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add three Bar button items using Flexible Space bar but the changes are not getting reflected in simulator. . I have pinned the navigation bar to bottom, left and right

[image: Screenshot of Simulator and Storyboard]

Comment: This should work fine if all constraints are set up properly and if the size class really fits the device/orientation. Have you tried to design this in wAny/hAny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use size class and auto layout, add constraints between your toolbar and the View: leading space = 0, trailing space = 0, bottom space = 0, heigh fixed.
You can add as much toolbar items as you wish until you have no space.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:undo, done, cancel, nil]];
```

or

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:undo, done, cancel, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to have images for buttons

Comment: Why is flexible space bar not working? Isn't that the sole purpose of Flexible Space bars?